# Unbuffered python coverage

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I want to run application in production with coverage enable.
The application is always up and do not stop its execution.
In each day I want to see coverage increase.
Unfortunately .coverage file appear on the disk only after application stop.

To simulate this behavior I have test.py

```
# cat test.py 
if 1==2:
    print(1)

if 2==2:
    print(2)

import time

i = 10
while i:
    print("sleep")
    time.sleep(1)
    i -= 1

print("end")
```

Which is launched like

```
python3 -u -m coverage run test.py 
2
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep # I want to be able to see coverage in this moment
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
end
```

Only after `end` word is printed I can see coverage file

```
ls -a
.  ..  .coverage  test.py
```

How can I force flushing/Unbuffering on py.coverage ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "In each day I want to see the coverage increase."  Why would your application run code on the second day that it didn't run on the first day?

Comment: it is an interactive application. In day 1 get input A, in day 2 get input B, in day 3 get a combination of A and B
so there are 3 branches to cover for three days

Comment: What is it you will learn from this coverage measurement?  Do you have an automated test suite that can give you coverage numbers?

Comment: @NedBatchelder I am searching for a solution about HOW ant not WHY to solve something. 
1. Of course I do not have automated case for input D,E,F ... (I have only for A, B and C).  
2. QA are doing some test each day and I need to be sure that they did their jobs properly.

Comment: When I get unusual questions from people using coverage.py, I like to find out as much as I can about their uses.  It helps me build a better product.

Comment: Well @NedBatchelder now I understand your interest in "why". You need to mention in firts place that you are part of pycoverage team ;). Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get coverage.py 4.5.1 to do this.  The 5.0 development switched the data storage to SQLite, so we should be able to add a feature to periodically flush the coverage data to the database.